# How to set max non-heap memory in a Java 8 (Spring Boot) application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory

I have 20 Spring Boot (2.3) embedded Tomcat applications running on a Linux machine with 8GB. All applications are Java 1.8 apps. The machine was running out of memory and Linux started killing some of my app processes as a result.

Using Linux top and Spring Boot admin, I noticed that the max memory heap was set to 2GB:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

As a result, each of the 20 apps are trying to get 2GB of heap size (1/4th of physical mem). Using Spring Boot admin I could see only ~128 MB is being used. So I reduced the max heap size to 512 via `java -Xmx512m ...` Now, Spring Boot admin shows:

[image]

1.33 GB is allocated to non-heap space but only 121 MB is being used. Why is so much being allocated to non-heap space? How can I reduce?

**Update**

According to top each Java process is taking around 2.4GB (VIRT):

```
KiB Mem :  8177060 total,   347920 free,  7127736 used,   701404 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1128444 total,  1119032 free,     9412 used.   848848 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  2547 admin    20   0  2.418g 0.372g 0.012g S  0.0  4.8  27:14.43 java
  .
  .
  .
```

**Update 2**

I ran `jcmd 7505 VM.native_memory` for one of the processes and it reported:

```
7505:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1438547KB, committed=296227KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=524288KB, committed=123808KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=524288KB, committed=123808KB)

-                     Class (reserved=596663KB, committed=83423KB)
                            (classes #15363)
                            (malloc=2743KB #21177)
                            (mmap: reserved=593920KB, committed=80680KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=33210KB, committed=33210KB)
                            (thread #32)
                            (stack: reserved=31868KB, committed=31868KB)
                            (malloc=102KB #157)
                            (arena=1240KB #62)

-                      Code (reserved=254424KB, committed=27120KB)
                            (malloc=4824KB #8265)
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=22296KB)

-                        GC (reserved=1742KB, committed=446KB)
                            (malloc=30KB #305)
                            (mmap: reserved=1712KB, committed=416KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=1315KB, committed=1315KB)
                            (malloc=60KB #277)
                            (arena=1255KB #9)

-                  Internal (reserved=2695KB, committed=2695KB)
                            (malloc=2663KB #19903)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=20245KB, committed=20245KB)
                            (malloc=16817KB #167011)
                            (arena=3428KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3407KB, committed=3407KB)
                            (malloc=9KB #110)
                            (tracking overhead=3398KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=558KB, committed=558KB)
                            (malloc=558KB)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all - no, 1.33GB is not *allocated*. On the screenshot you have 127MB of nonheap memory allocated. The 1.33GB is the max limit.

I see your metaspace is about 80MB which should not pose a problem. The rest of the memory can be composed by a lot of things. Compressed classes, code cache, native buffers etc...

To get the detailed view of what is eating up the offheap memory, you can query the MBean `java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=*`, for example via VisualVM with an MBean plugin.

However, your apps may simply be eating too much *native* memory. For example many I/O buffers from Netty may be the culprit (used up by the `java.nio.DirectByteBuffer`). If that's the culprit, you can for example limit the caching of the `DirectByteBuffer`s with the flag `-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize`, or place a limit with `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`.
For a definitive answer of *what exactly* is eating your RAM, you'd have to create a heap dump and analyze it.

So to answer your question "Why is so much being allocated to non-heap space? How can I reduce?" There's not a lot allocated to non-heap space. Most of it is native buffers for I/O, and JVM internals. There is no universal switch or flag to limit all the different caches and pools at once.

Now to adress the elephant in the room. I think your **real** issue stems from simply having very little RAM. You've said you are running 20 instances of JVM limited to 512MB of heap space on 8GB machine. That is unsustainable. 20 x 512MB = 10GB of heap, which is more than you can accommodate with 8GB of total RAM. And that is before you even count in the off-heap/native memory. You need to either provide more HW resources, decrease the JVM count or further decrease the heap/metaspace and other limits (which I strongly advise not to).

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. I still have one doubt though. According to top, the VIRT of each of my Java processes is ~2.4GB. If only 512 MB heap space + 127 MB non heap is allocated, then why does VIRT report 2.5GB?

Comment: The VIRT of top is virtual memory https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html  It includes all code, data and shared libraries plus pages that have been swapped out and pages that have been mapped but not used. So it is a lot of things summed together, I'd wager most of it is shared between processes. The RES (resident memory) stat is much more informant - although still contains a little bit of unused memory pages, that were not reclaimed. In your case it shows 0.372g which is not a huge amount.

Comment: I thought top only showed memory exclusively allocated to one process. I ran `jmcd` (updated info in my OP). It shows committed ~300MB but reserved ~1.4GB.

Comment: Well, great, that aligns with what we've seen so far. 1.4GB of reserved, which is basically a limit of entire memory with committed/allocated 300MB of that space. Heap looks just as expected - 512MB max limit and 120MB used. 80MB of Metaspace (the "Class" stat). 32MB is occupied by thread stacks and the rest of the stuff is even smaller than that. 300MB x 20 ~= 6GB, so you are running dangerously close to the RAM limit (leaving some for the OS and other processes). Now if a sudden load would show up on one or some of the JVMs it could easily hit a cap.

Comment: Thanks Leprechaun. I added 32GB physical memory to the box. Now, `top` is showing 3.3GB free. I expected a lot more free memory than that. I've kept the heap space of each JVM to 512MB max so not sure why only 3.3GB is free.

Comment: Well, the 512MB limit is applied only to heap space. Technically metaspace is unbounded, and a lot of memory in linux is used for various caches, that can be freed by the kernel when needed. Modern memory management is quite complex, not everything that is allocated must be used or stay unreclaimed. E.g. there is a natural tendency for the OS (even for Windows) to preallocate more memory than currently needed to prevent unexpected stalls when sudden memory requirements spike up due to system load. Is a significant part of the memory occupied by the "buff/cache"? If so it's nothing worrisome

Comment: Here's a good answer if you want to turn Netty's direct buffer off - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069998/2400151

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been stated, [here's](https://stuefe.de/posts/metaspace/what-is-metaspace/) a very good article about the Metaspace in the JVM which by defaults reserves about 1GB (though it may not actually use that much). So that's another thing you can tune using the flag `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` if you have many small apps and want to decrease the amount of memory used/reserved.